# Convert byte[] to string and back again

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have an application that is storing the IP Addresses of requests in the database as a varbinary(16) in a manner described here: [Byte Array Size for a IPv6 IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115463/byte-array-size-for-a-ipv6-ip-address).

I need to pass the IP Address from one server to another. For that reason, I cannot just rely on the Request object. My question is, if I have the IP Address as a byte[], how do I encode it as a string and then decode it as a byte[] again? I always get confused with the ASCII, UTF8, Unicode, etc. encodings.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ipString = (new IPAddress(myBytes)).ToString()
```

then at the other end

```
var addressBytes = IPAddress.Parse(ipString).GetAddressBytes();
```

Comment: @Yuck: No it doesn't. Try it. It will give you a human readable representation of an IP address, the most portable way of trafficking it between nodes.

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly more user-friendly string representation, you can use [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

```
str = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(str);
```

Comment: Arbitrary bytes will **not** conform to arbitrary encodings. -1

Comment: For instance: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[]{255,255,255,255}))` will hand you back an array {63,63,63,63}. Worse than useless.

Comment: @spender Point taken. I've removed the section of my answer referencing `Encoding`.